# How to implement a complex shouldComponentUpdate with useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a container component which I want to convert to a functional component and use react hooks, like useEffect. However, I have a quite complex shouldComponentUpdate function, which does some logic based on current props and state, and next props and state, to prevent unnecessary rendering.

Here is my shouldComponentUpdate function:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    const { current, id, language: { isRtl }, query: { response: { cookie, hits } } } = this.props;
    if (nextProps.language.isRtl !== isRtl) {
        return true;
    }
    const { selected } = this.state;
    if (current !== nextProps.current) {
        if  (id === nextProps.current) {
            if  (nextProps.direction !== 0) {
                this.select(nextProps.direction > 0 ? 0 : hits.length - 1, true);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (selected >= 0) {
                this.setState({ selected: -1 });
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (cookie === null && nextState.selected !== selected) {
        const redrawHit = (index, className) => {
            if (index >= 0) {
                hits[index].ref.current.updateState({ className });
            }
        };
        redrawHit(nextState.selected, 'hit-selected');
        redrawHit(selected, 'hit-deselected');
    }
    return cookie !== null;
}
```

I wasn't able to find a proper way to implement it via useEffect hook. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You don't. First of all, functional components don't have anything like `nextState` or `nextProps` They only have the current `state` and `props`, and you can remember/store the previous ones. But when you access them, you're already inside the render function. What makes your code really hard to translate is the fact that your `shouldComponentUpdate` method has side effects, where it updates `state` and calls other methods. All of which would also have to be inside the `render` method of a FC, as a FC is basically just a big `render` method.

Comment: FC are not the solution to every problem. Maybe you'd want to break down the code in your current component into multiple smaller components and compose them. Or you show us the whole class and maybe we can recommend another approach.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for your reply. The whole class is too big to fit in here. Can you give me an email so that I can send it to you?

Comment: *"The whole class is too big to fit in here."* Then you certainbly should break it up. How do you keep the oversight? *"Can you give me an email so that I can send it to you?"* No, I don't do that. The unspoken "arrangement" here on SO is that people answer when they want, and if they want. I won't change that to a pseudo-consultant relation. If you're afraid that the big class will clutter up the question, you could put it inside a (hidden) snippet. Or you could create a snippet/fiddle/pen with just the relevant parts.

Comment: @Thomas, I am deeply sorry if I was rude. I had no intention at all. I am new here and of course you only answer what you want, if you want. Please accept my apology. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: No need for an apology, I didn't take it as rude. I just tried to communicate, that going away from SO to a direct email contact would shift the relationship between us in a way that I don't want. From a casual *can you guys take a look at this and give me input* to something closer, more personal and more obligatory. So everything fine. I'm here on SO because I want to help, but I also want to keep it casual.

Comment: Try to read about [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate), and see if that fits your requirement, that may solve your problem.